# How to close right sidebar when clicked outside the sidebar Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am having trouble closing my sidebar on outside click, can't get it to work.
I was trying to add addEventListener to window via conditional statement, but it didn't work.

HTML

```
<li class="back-btn">
    <div class="mobile-back text-right" (click)="mainMenuToggle()">
      <span>{{"back" | translate}}</span>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right pl-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</li>
```

TypeScript

```
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

public menuItems: Menu[];

constructor(private router: Router, public navServices: NavService) {
  this.navServices.items.subscribe(menuItems => this.menuItems = menuItems );
  this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  this.navServices.mainMenuToggle = false;
});
}

ngOnInit(): void {
}

mainMenuToggle(): void {
  this.navServices.mainMenuToggle = !this.navServices.mainMenuToggle;
}
// Click Toggle menu (Mobile)
toggletNavActive(item) {
  item.active = !item.active;
  }
}
```

Comment: Here's an example of how to do what you asking https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-sidenav-experiments.